# Conditional query to return variable from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to do some conditional queries on Azure SQL, but Im totally lost on how to do it.
I have these two tables:

#### Order Table

```
OrderID (PK)
...
```

#### OrderHistory Table

```
OrderHistoryId (PK)
OrderId (FK)
DisplayString
OrderStatus
```

---

Now what I want to do is join the table OrderHistory to my query, and return a variable based on some conditional queries against OrderHistory

```sql
SELECT O.OrderId, [...], Variable
FROM [Order] AS O

-- some code to get "Variable" from OrderHistory

ORDER BY O.OrderId DESC

OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
```

#### Conditions

1. If any of the rows associated with O.OrderId contain %FINISHED% in DisplayString OR OrderStatus = 1; then return 1
2. If any of the rows associated with O.OrderId contain OrderStatus = 2 AND NOT %FINISHED% in DisplayString; then return  2
3. If the SUM of all OrderStatus associated with O.OrderId is equal to 0; then return 3

#### Result

Here's what I want as a result:

```
OrderId    [...]    Variable
1           ...     1
2           ...     3
3           ...     2
4           ...     2
```

Answer (score 1):

User [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement as per the taste of your sql.

Comment: Could you show the OP an example?  As it is both CASE and an aggregated query.

Comment: An example would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This query might need some more work, but it should demonstrate the "case":

```
select Variable = case when b.DisplayString like 'FINISHED%' or b.OrderStatus = 1
                       then 1
                       else case when b.DisplayString not like 'FINISHED%' and b.OrderStatus = 2
                            then 2
                            else case when c.sumOsStatus = 0 then 3
                            end
                       end
                  end,
* 
from [Order] a
inner join OrderHistory b
    on a.OrderId = b.OrderId
inner join (select OrderId, sum(OrderStatus) sumOsStatus from OrderHistory group by OrderId) c
    on a.OrderId = c.OrderId
```